# Creating GUI with RUBY

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, jruby

I am very impressed with Ruby, and I am experimenting with JRuby in NetBeans. But it's hard to get more than a smattering of information on using JRuby with Swing.  At the moment, I have the following program, which works, except for the commented line.

```
require 'java'

include_class 'java.awt.event.ActionListener'
include_class 'javax.swing.JButton'
include_class 'javax.swing.JFrame'

class ClickAction
   include ActionListener

   def actionPerformed(event)
      puts "Button clicked"
   end
end #ClickAction

class MainWindow < JFrame
   def initialize
      super "JRuby Swing Demo"
      setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame::EXIT_ON_CLOSE
      button = JButton.new "Click me"
      button.setSize 30, 100                  #this line does nothing
      button.addActionListener ClickAction.new
      add button        
      pack
   end
end

mainWindow = MainWindow.new
mainWindow.setSize 300, 300
mainWindow.setVisible(true)
```

When I run this, the button automatically expands to occupy the whole window.
So why does "setSize" work on the main window, but not on the button.

Also, it there a "setBounds" method analogous to that in Java?

Thanks for any help with this.  I code my own layouts in Java, and that is what I'd like to do  in JRuby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the layout of mainWindow and is the same behaviour that you'd have if this was written in Java. The default is [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), which changes the size of the frame's contents. You could try using something like [FlowLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) instead.

There certainly is a `setBounds` method.